# Cannot convert DateTime from 12hr to 24hr format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am converting a DateTime from 12 hours to 24 hours format

Here is the time that I am getting from a Textbox:

```
03/23/2015 6:20 PM
```

I want to convert to `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format

I tried:

```
Datetime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which is giving my Invalid input string error.

I tried `Convert.ToDatetime` also, but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string dateString = "03/23/2015 6:20 PM";

var date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Have you watched your date? How could the month be in second place? What month is 23, `Frugoloth`? And the seconds, are there seconds in your date?

The things that you could not know: `tt` is for the PM, and a single `h` because you accept single digit hours (`6`).